# Create a view of users to show their profile visits

Tags: views

I need to track the IP address in order to have a good idea on how many users visit each profile. This report will be available only to the admin.

I have used [User Visits Advanced](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_visits_adv) module

**The problem is that even user can also see his profile visits by using this module.I was also trying to figuring out how to create view of recent visitors using this module but finally unsuccessful.**

I just want to create view report of users and their respective profile visits .

Comment: What about https://www.drupal.org/project/visits

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply creating a rule for profile clicks and add an action i.e. a counter that accepts +1 everytime the event occurs (Rules module).
To create a profile click action, all you need is the uid (user ID) which can be like this `example.com/user?q=uid`.
create a field in my accounts which stores this value and keep it hidden with display suite. In views, show the profile as fields and choose the uid and your recent field to display profile visits. Style it with css. sorry for bad english I am spanish